# Können die Adverbien Substantive bestimmen?

Tags: adverb

Hier kommen zwei Sätze:

> **Heute Morgen** ging er in die Schule.

und

> Wir haben etwas **sehr Schönes** auf dem Land gefunden.

"Heute" und "sehr" sind Adverbien, aber sie dürfen hinsichtlich der Sätze die folgenden Substantive bestimmen. Warum?

Comment: Ich verstehe nicht, was du mit "dürfen Substantive bestimmen" meinst. Das Adverb im ersten und das im Zweiten (das keins ist) haben keinen Einfluß auf die Substantive im Satz.

Comment: @tofro: mit Substantive sind *Morgen* und *Schönes* gemeint, und *heute* und *sehr* beziehen sich auf diese Substantive, zumindest kann man es so auffassen. Ich finde die Frage schon nachvollziehbar.

Answer (score 6):

In *heute Morgen* ist *heute* kein Attribut von *Morgen*, sondern *Morgen* ist ein Zusatz zu *heute*, der die Zeit näher bestimmt. Vergleiche die ungefähr gleichbedeutenden Wortgruppen *heute frühmorgens* oder *heute am frühen Morgen*.

In *sehr Schönes* ist *Schönes* ein **substantiviertes Adjektiv**. Es vereinigt daher Eigenschaften eines Substantivs und eines Adjektivs und kann analog zu einem reinen Adjektiv von einem Adverb näher bestimmt werden.